# Mejor indexación de mi sitio web

Tags: html, web, seo

Tengo un problema con mi página web, y es que por mucho que organice el contenido, no consigo que me indexe correctamente cada apartado.

Me gustaría que quedara como este ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, yo en mi página web solo consigo mostrar el title y el description.

¿Algún consejo?

No adjunto mi código pues es un montón, y tampoco quiero hacer spam de mi contenido.

Comment: El tema es que el ejemplo que pones es un sitio web que ha pagado por aparecer el primero. De hecho en el buscador el primer resultado suele ser un anuncio y si no lo es no suele tener los cuatro apartados de debajo que entiendo que son los que tú buscas que te salgan. Si buscas Wikipedia en google por ejemplo no salen esas secciones porque no es un anuncio.

Comment: No sé si las preguntas sobre SEO son validas en [StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Google decide si tu sitio va a mostrar los enlaces a las secciones, no es fácil, normalmente solo webs muy importantes lo consiguen: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=es&vid=0-386358760571-1537451447538